# Async/Await - Await not holding as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

When performing a long running operation I noticed that i could kickstart a long running sub-operation right off the start line and do other stuff while it fetches results from caches/databases.

The given operation is:

```
public async Task<Fichaclis> Finalize()
{
     using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
     {
         transactionTimer.Start();
         var agendasTransitionTask = ExecuteAgendas();

                ... DO ALOT OF SYNC OPERATIONS ...
         await agendasTransitionTask;
         transaction.Complete();
     }
}
private Task ExecuteAgendas()
{
    return ags.GetAgendas().ContinueWith((prev) =>
    {
        var currentAgendas = prev.Result;
        foreach (var item in currentAgendas)
        {
            ... DO QUICK SYNC STUFF...
        }
        return ags.BulkEditAgenda(currentAgendas);
    });
}
```

GetAgendas is a method used all over with the following signature:
`public async Task<List<Agendas>> GetAgendas()`
because it's widely used, i believe the problem is not there. As for `BulkEditAgenda`:

```
public async Task BulkEditAgenda(IEnumerable<Agendas> agendas)
{
    if (agendas == null || agendas.Count() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    var t1 = AddOrUpdateCache(agendas);
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in agendas)
            {
                EditNoReconnection(item);
            }
            Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log
            throw;
        }
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
```

`EditNoReconnect` and `Save` are both sync methods.

```
private Task AddOrUpdateCache(IEnumerable<Agendas> agendas)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in agendas)
    {
        tasks.Add(TryGetCache(item)
            .ContinueWith((taskResult) =>
            {
                ...DO QUICK SYNC STUFF...
            })
        );
    }
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

`TryGetCache` is also a widely used method, so I think it's safe... it's signature is `private Task<AgendasCacheLookupResult> TryGetCache(`

So, resuming the issue at hand: For a small set of items do in the sync session of the `Finalize` method the command `transaction.Complete()` is execute before `Save()` (inside BulkEditAgendas). For a regular or large amount of items, it works as expected.
This means that i'm not chaining the `Tasks` correctly, or my understanding of how Async/Await + Tasks/ContinueWith works is fundamentally incorrect.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `ContinueWith` and `Result` in `ExecuteAgendas`?  Why not simply `await` the result returned by `GetAgendas` to extract the value when it is ready?

Comment: @EricLippert inherited code... i'm in favor of `await` too but it seems that a lot of code was written before async\await was made available... the whole code is full of cases like this one...

Comment: @EricLippert there are some instances where the ContinueWith can indeed be executed whenever (fire & forget) but, obviously not in this case

Comment: @Leonardo: `ContinueWith` in asynchronous code can *always* be replaced with `await`. Sometimes you need to add an `async` method to do so, but it's always possible (and better).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
private Task ExecuteAgendas()
{
    return ags.GetAgendas().ContinueWith((prev) =>
    {
        var currentAgendas = prev.Result;
        foreach (var item in currentAgendas)
        {
            ... DO QUICK SYNC STUFF...
        }
        return ags.BulkEditAgenda(currentAgendas);
    });
}
```

First, what you return from this is the continuation task (result of `ContinueWith`). But body of `ContinueWith` ends when you do

```
return ags.BulkEditAgenda(currentAgendas);
```

So body of continuation ends potentially **before** `BulkEditAgenda` task is completed (you don't wait in any way for completion of `BulkEditAgenda`). So this line

```
await agendasTransitionTask;
```

Returns while `BulkEditAgenda` is still in progress. To clarify even more, note that what is returned from `ExecuteAgendas` is `Task<Task>` and result of `await agendasTransitionTask` is `Task` which represents your running `BulkEditAgenda`.

To fix, just use async\await like you do everywhere else:

```
private async Task ExecuteAgendas() {
   var currentAgengas = await ags.GetAgendas();            
   foreach (var item in currentAgendas) {    
       // do stuff            
   }
   await ags.BulkEditAgenda(currentAgendas);
}
```